# Erasing redundant expression with llvm and local value numbering algorithm

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

So my C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int a, b,c, d;
    b = 18, c = 112;
    b = a - d;
    d = a - d;
}
```

and part of its IR is:

```
  %5 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %6 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %7 = sub nsw i32 %5, %6
  store i32 %7, i32* %2, align 4

  %8 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  %9 = load i32, i32* %4, align 4
  %10 = sub nsw i32 %8, %9
  store i32 %10, i32* %4, align 4
```

I have implemented LVN algorithm to detect the redundant expression which is d = a - d. Now for optimization, I need to manipulate the instruction and make it d = b. I am not sure how to do it with llvm and how I can manipulate the IR.

I am new in llvm so it might be a silly question but I am really confused. Since, llvm works on IR, I understand that when it see "d = a - d" it will first load a and d, but the binary operation and store instruction in IR needs to be changed so that %4 gets the value from %2. Can anyone help me checking if I am understanding this correctly and how I can manipulate the IR to optimize the code.

Comment: None of those instructions has an effect and they can all be removed.  You at least have to return a result.

Comment: By returning result do you mean to say to set the value of b to d? As in d=b? That's what I am trying to do using llvm but not sure how I can do that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: No, I mean return from the function.  In the presence of optimizations your complete function will be optimized out because it has no side effects: https://godbolt.org/g/C156Cc

Comment: okay I understand that. But I am trying to write an optimization pass that will erase the redundant expression. So, let's say the function returns something. Now what component of llvm I can use to write a pass that erases the redundant expression d=a-d and replace it with d=b? Can you help me with that?

Comment: Note that LLVM already performs this optimization. So if this is anything other than a learning exercise, you don't need to do this at all.

Comment: Yes. It's a learning exercise for me. I am trying to implement some of the optimizations llvm already does.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's replace your example program with one that does not invoke undefined behaviour (due to accessing uninitialized variables), so that the UB does not confuse the issue:

```
void f(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    b = a - d;
    d = a - d;
    // Code that uses b and d
}
```

(I've also removed the two assignments as they didn't have any effect and will disappear after `mem2reg` anyway.)

Now to actually answer your question: Most optimizations run after the `mem2reg` pass, which converts memory accesses to registers where possible. This is important because, unlike memory locations, LLVM registers can only be assigned from a single point in the source, so `mem2reg` turns the code into SSA form, which is required for many optimizations to work.

If we apply `mem2reg` to the example code, we get:

```
define void @f(i32, i32, i32, i32) #0 {
  %5 = sub nsw i32 %0, %3
  %6 = sub nsw i32 %0, %3
  ; Code that uses b and d
}
```

So now we'd apply your analysis to find out that `%6` is equivalent to `%5`. With that information we can remove the definition of `%6` and replace all the occurrences of `%6` with `%5` (note that this would be more complicated if `%5` and `%6` were in the different basic blocks where one didn't dominate the other). To do that you can find all uses of `%6` using the `uses()` method, which tells you which instructions have `%6` as which operand. Then you can just set that operand to be a reference to `%5` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Helps a lot